# Declare a new variable in if statement C

Tags: arrays, c, function, variables, parameters

I have an  `Insert` function in which there is a `char` such as parameter. With this parameter (`type`) I decide the type of pos. For example: if I call  `Insert('i')` I am specifying that I have to use an Int. The trouble is if I declare a new parameter in every if statement , outside of if , it doesn't see the variable. In my case , `printf("%d", array[pos]);` it tells me that `pos` isn't initialized. How can I resolve it?

**insert.c**

```
void insert(char type){
    if(type=='i'){
        int pos;
    }else if(type=='f' || type=='d'){
        double pos;
    }else if(type=='c'){
        char pos;
    }else if(type=='s'){
        char *pos;
    }else {
        int pos;
    }

    int array[2];
       //I put some values in the array.
    printf("%d", array[pos]);
```

**main.c**

```
int main(){
    char c = 'i';
    insert(c);
```

Comment: That's not how C works, you can't just "change" the type of a variable. All those declarations are completely independent of each other, which is why they all only exist in their own scopes

Comment: You can't do this, but what is more important is what you're actually trying to accomplish. Does it make sense to index an array with a `double` or a `char*`? Can you explain a bit what you're thinking or expand the code to be less vague?

Comment: This looks like a typical [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a variable is the block in which it is declared. That means that the `pos` variable vanishes as soon as it reaches the closing bracket. That construct allows you to use the same name for different types, but C does not allow you to use the variable outside of the block where it was declared.

What you need here is a union, and to be able to use it correctly, I would advise you to include it into a struct along with an indication of its type:

```
struct variant {
    enum {i, d, c, s} type;
    union {
        int i;
        double d;
        char c;
        char *s;
    };
};
```

You can then use it:

```
void insert(char type){
    variant pos;
    if(type=='i'){
        pos.type = i;
    }else if(type=='f' || type=='d'){
        pos.type = f;
    }else if(type=='c'){
        pos.type = c;
    }else if(type=='s'){
        pos.type = s;
    }else {
        pos.type = i;
    }

    ...
    if (pos.type == i) {
        printf("%d", array[pos.i]);
```

Comment: Subject to this being an appropriate solution for the OP's specific use case, yes.